# Can not run firebase commands in console: Error(`@grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ${supportedNodeVersions}`)

Tags: firebase, grpc, grpc-node

In terminal when I run firebase... gives the following error:

```
Error(`@grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ${supportedNodeVersions}`)
```

How can I delete this grpc? or what should I do?

Comment: Is that the actual console output you got? If not, what did you get in the console?

Comment: @murgatroid99 yes it is what I got

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you using that doesn't understand backticked templated strings? https://node.green/ seems to indicate you'd be running nodejs 0.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that you need a newer version of Node.js to run that library. Currently, the latest LTS is version 12.x, but recent versions of 10.x should also work well.